# Поиск по нескольким свойствам в MySQL по динамическим записям?

Tags: sql

подскажите пожалуйста как произвести поиск в MySQL по полному совпадению в условии по нескольким параметрам?

Имеется таблица следующего вида: https://hsto.org/webt/vz/rg/oo/vzrgoomme1shieblbczytntsg9y.png

Как мне вернуть количество только в случае его полного совпадения по всем полям?

Пробую вот так, выбранные результаты соответствуют всем критериям, но возвращается 0.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_options AS PO
WHERE
(PO.classifier_id = 1 AND PO.option_id IN (5))
AND
(PO.classifier_id = 3 AND PO.option_id IN (29))
AND
(PO.classifier_id = 4 AND PO.option_id IN (55, 57, 59))
```

Comment: classifier_id не может быть равен 1, 3 и 4 одновременно, он может быть равен только чему-то одному. Может, вам нужно заменить AND на OR?

Comment: Не совсем уверен правильно ли я составил запрос, можете пожалуйста глянуть SELECT * FROM products AS P
LEFT JOIN product_categories AS PC ON PC.product_id = P.id
WHERE
PC.category_id = 3
AND
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_options AS PO
    WHERE
    (
        PO.classifier_id = 1 AND PO.option_id IN (5)
    )
    OR
    (
        PO.classifier_id = 3 AND PO.option_id IN (29)
    )
    OR
    (
        PO.classifier_id = 4 AND PO.option_id IN (55, 57, 59)
    )
) >= 3

Comment: В вашем изначальном запросе поменять условия на OR, добавить group by по полю для какой сущьности вы эти условия считаете (видимо product_id) и `having count(distinct classifier_id) = 3`. Или having count(1)=5 если надо убедится что все option_id в правильных значениях

Comment: @Mike, Можете пожалуйста добавить в ответы, спасибо